# Time complexity measured as a function of the number of bits in the input?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity

I came across this problem that I am not sure how to solve:

> Suppose A(.) is a subroutine that takes as input a number in binary, and takes linear time (that is, O(n), where n is the length (in bits) of the number).
>   Consider the following piece of code, which starts with an n-bit number x.

```
while x>1:
  call A(x)
  x=x-1
```

> Assume that the subtraction takes O(n) time on an n-bit number.
>
> (a) How many times does the inner loop iterate (as a function of n)? Leave your answer in big-O form.
>
> (b) What is the overall running time (as a function of n), in big-O form?

My guess is that (a) is O(n^2) and (b) is O(n^3). Is this correct? The way I'm thinking about it is that the loop has to compute two steps each time it cycles through and it will cycle through x time each time subtracting 1 from n bits until x reaches 0.  And for part b since A(.) takes time O(n) we multiply that with the time it takes to execute the loop and we then have the over all running time. Is my analysis correct?

Answer (score 7):

Something that might help here is to write x = 2<sup>n</sup>, since if x has n bits its value is O(2<sup>n</sup>). Therefore, the loop will run O(2<sup>n</sup>) times.

Each iteration of the loop does O(n) work, giving an upper bound on the work of O(n · 2<sup>n</sup>). This bound ends up being tight. Notice that for the first x/2 iterations of the loop, the value of x will still need n bits. Therefore, as a lower bound on the work done, we get x/2 = 2<sup>n-1</sup> iterations doing n work each, giving a total of Ω(n · 2<sup>n</sup>) work. Thus the work done is Θ(n · 2<sup>n</sup>).

Hope this helps!